# How can I convert a gif image file from Bit depth 24 to Bit depth 8?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tried this

```
var test = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Downloaded Images\New folder",
                                     "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(test[i]);
                Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(orig.Width, orig.Height,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
                {
                    gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
                }
            }
```

If I change this line to 24 it will work fine but the images are already Bit depth 24

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
```

When I change the line to 8

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed
```

I'm getting exception
On the line

```
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
```

System.Exception: 'A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.'

There is no Format8bppRgb option.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no `Format8bppRgb` option because 8-bit images are either grayscale without color, or color with a palette and therefore always indexed.

If your goal is to make an identical copy of the original 8-bit image, you can use the `Clone()` method like this:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap orig = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(GifFile);
System.Drawing.Bitmap clone = orig.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, orig.Width, orig.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

However, if your goal is to use Graphics to draw other objects on the bitmap, you can convert the 8-bit image to 24-bit, draw on it, then convert it back to 8-bit. It is explained in Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) that Graphics.FromImage does not work if "the image has an indexed pixel format" like 8-bit.

Converting to 24-bit is fairly easy, but converting back to 8-bit can be tricky because you will need to create a suitable palette and match the colors to it so as not to lose too many of the original colors or change the appearance of the image.

If you want to use `Graphics` drawing **without** changing from 8-bit, you can use a professional imaging SDK like LEADTOOLS (disclosure: I work for its vendor). Here’s the code that does that:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap orig = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(GifFile);
Leadtools.RasterImage LEADClone = Leadtools.Drawing.RasterImageConverter.ConvertFromImage(orig, Leadtools.Drawing.ConvertFromImageOptions.None);
Leadtools.Drawing.RasterImageGdiPlusGraphicsContainer container = new Leadtools.Drawing.RasterImageGdiPlusGraphicsContainer(LEADClone);
container.Graphics.DrawImage(orig, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, orig.Width, orig.Height));
```

The SDK also contains the [ColorResolutionCommand Class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/l/imageprocessing-colorresolutioncommand.html), which can convert to 8-bits (or any bits-per-pixel) and produce optimized palettes if needed.

If you would like to try LEADTOOLS, you can obtain a [free evaluation here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads)